# Include returned column from groupby.apply to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df=

```
            timestamp    A     B
0 2021-05-14 15:25:00  1.70    1
1 2021-05-14 15:26:00  1.55    3
2 2021-05-15 15:27:00  1.10    4
3 2021-05-15 15:28:00  1.20    2
4 2021-05-15 15:29:00  1.50    2
```

Want to do some custom calculation as shown with: `df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.date]).apply(custFun)`

```
def custFun(x):
    d = {}
    d['C']=(x['A']*x['B']).sum()/x['B'].sum()
    d['D']=(x['B']/x['A']).sum()/len(x)
    return pd.Series(d)
```

Now, what I want is to add returned dataframe to the existing `df`, similar to:

```
            timestamp    A     B       C      D
0 2021-05-14 15:25:00  1.70    1    1.58    1.26
1 2021-05-14 15:26:00  1.55    3            
2 2021-05-15 15:27:00  1.10    4    1.22    2.21
3 2021-05-15 15:28:00  1.20    2            
4 2021-05-15 15:29:00  1.50    2
```

I think I require to use `transform` or `Series.map`. However, unable to grasp the concept. Any help?

Edit: `timestamp` is not index. Placement of Column `C` values, is on the 1st row of the new date with respect to `timestamp`.

Edit2: updated `custFun` and required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking clues from Quang Hoang's answer:

```
dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date

r=df.groupby(dates).apply(custFun)

df.loc[~dates.duplicated(), 'C'] = dates.map(r['C'].squeeze())
df.loc[~dates.duplicated(), 'D'] = dates.map(r['D'].squeeze())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specific `custFunc` can be better done with:

```
dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date

# C column - calculate the weighted average for the dates
# then map it back
weighted_avg = df.groupby(dates).apply(lambda x: (x['A']*x['B']).sum()/x['B'].sum())
df.loc[~dates.duplicated(), 'C'] = dates.map(weighted_avg)

# D Column no need groupby here
df['D'] = df['B']/df['A']
```

Output:

```
            timestamp     A  B       C         D
0 2021-05-14 15:25:00  1.70  1  1.5875  0.588235
1 2021-05-14 15:26:00  1.55  3     NaN  1.935484
2 2021-05-15 15:27:00  1.10  4  1.2250  3.636364
3 2021-05-15 15:28:00  1.20  2     NaN  1.666667
4 2021-05-15 15:29:00  1.50  2     NaN  1.333333
```

Comment: need `custFun`, there are multiple calculations. Any other way around?

Comment: Wrap all the code above inside a `custFun` and pass `df` to it. That makes more sense since you're modifying the dataframe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the initial answers and comments, here's a starting point for you. I think what you are missing on the custom function is how to modify the df with the result.

You want to operate on x and return x

```
def custFun(x):
    x['C']=(x['A']*x['B']).sum()/x['B'].sum()
    x['D']=x['B']/x['A']
    return x
```

when you call it like this, it will create C and D on the existing dataframe. You'll need to adapt to get exactly what you want as output.